# Multiple leveles nested components in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

I am using Angular 5+ and I want to create 3 levels up nested components.

Here is an example of what I can do.

```
<my-app>
<first></first>
<second></second>
</myapp>
```

And here is what I **cannot** do.

```
<my-app>
<first><second></second></first>
</myapp>
```

I have the following code in my app module.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AboutPage,FirstComponent,SecondComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(AboutPage),
    ],
})

export class AppModule{}
```

Note here that AppModule is not the root module but it is lazyLoaded Component as well.

Comment: Can you expand your question, not really sure what you're asking

Comment: What does it mean that "AppModule" is not the root module"? The "AppModule" is always the root module, if it actually isn't, don't call it "AppModule". If you do it in your code for whatever reason, then so be it, but please don't do it for SO questions. This only causes confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to implement the `<second></second>` component inside of the `<first></first>`'s components template.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'first',
  template: '<second></second>'
})
export class FirstComponent { ... }
```

your module is correct

Answer (score 1):

`MyAppComponent` needs to have an `<ng-content>` element, otherwise it won't display projected content.

Caution: This only works for components that are not the root component. Angular doesn't support projecting content to the root component. See comment below the question to see what causes the confusion.